# UTF-8 encoded text erroneously displayed in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, character-encoding, meta-tags

The following document is saved as UTF-8 without bom:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>AB - Adasdajhasbkfjqnefibqfn     </title>        
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.my-domain.net/bilder/favicon.ico" >
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'UA*******-1', 'my-domain.net');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">   
        <link href="http://www.does-not-exists.net/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>   

    <body>
    <p>äöü</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I load this page then I see correctly: äöü.

When I load the page from another page through a form like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name='mainForm' action='step2t.php' enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method='post'>            
            <input type='submit' >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I see äöü in **Chrome** and even correctly in **IE 8**, but in **Firefox** I get

Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼

Now, if I delete any of the following lines:

```
<title>AB - Adasdajhasbkfjqnefibqfn     </title>
```

---

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.my-domain.net/bilder/favicon.ico" >
```

---

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

---

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
   ga('create', 'UA*******-1', 'my-domain.net');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   </script>
```

---

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
```

---

```
 <link href="http://www.does-not-exists.net/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

then it suddenly **works** in Firefox.

Any clue why this document is not working properly in Firefox?

Comment: Your `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"...` tag should be the first tag after `<head>`.

Comment: What is your Firefox version ?

Comment: @tcooc OMG - IT WORKED. I SPEND THE LAST 3 HOURS ON THAT PROBLEM. Can you please post this as an answer so I can check it?

Comment: @curiosu its Version 31.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" ...>` tag should be the first tag after the opening `<head>` tag, since it tells the browser what charset the rest of the document uses (browsers will guess the charset before this point).

Source: [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) (see Notes section)

Note that it's not *mandatory* to have it be the first tag (it can appear anywhere within the first 512 bytes), but doing so is a good rule of thumb and prevents the need to count 512 bytes on all your html documents.

Comment: It does not need to be the first, but it needs to be appear “early enough” in the data stream, otherwise browsers may guess on the encoding before they see the tag.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela True, but it is a good rule of thumb. It would be pretty tedious counting 512 bytes for each html file to check. Editing question to point this out.

Comment: In future, whenever something is not working with my html document, I am going to check that thing first :D. Thank you so much!